# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task

Tags: android, firebase, exception

I'm working on my app which uses firebase. On one of my phone everything is working as expected (Android 5.0.2) but when i conntected my older phone which has also Lolipop, I encoutered Nullpointer exception during evoke method "singupwithemailandpassword"

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdd)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvv.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwc.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.mateusz.raehme.activities.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:79)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Does anybody know what causes that issue?

Comment: Does this phone have google service?

Comment: I don't  really know, how should i check if it has?

Comment: https://www.androidpit.com/install-google-play-services-apk

Comment: This device does not have a compatible version of Google Play services installed.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48975027/4815718

Answer (score 0):

Guessing by the error messages on trying to bring up the signup screen, the older version of android uses a different type of the authentication or a different system altogether. Because of that, the different system or older version uses a different method, so it thinks the references that work with the newer system are null, or different altogether.

That's my useless 2 cents.